# SimpleXMLElement::addChild doesn't seem to work with certain strings

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cdata

In the effiliation pluggin for prestashop, i've found this code:

```
$values->addChild('marque', '<![CDATA['.$product['manufacturer_name'].']]>');
```

when in `$product['manufacturer_name']`, i have `Cyril & Nathalie Daniel`, the output is `<![CDATA[Cyril`,
as opposed to the normal case: `<![CDATA[Foo Bar]]>`

Can the 2nd argument of [SimpleXMLElement::addChild](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) can contain `&` ? Do i have to use some htmlentities on the manufacturer name ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260224/how-to-write-cdata-using-simplexmlelement

Comment: @salathe This is indeed the right thing to do. But i am not supposed to modify a paid module, so i'd prever a quick dirty fix.

Comment: Surely a quick, dirty fix is still modifying the code. Either way, you know how this should be done.

Comment: if you first only ``$foo = $xml->addChild('foo')`` and set the value after adding the child  ``$foo[0] = 'value & txt'`` then simpleXML does escape the ampersand ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem is described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php#103587):

> Note that although addChild() escapes "<" and ">", it does not escape
>   the ampersand "&".

---

The solution proposed php.net (htmlentities or htmlcspecialchars) is not a good one, so i came up with what salathe suggested:

```
<?php
class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement // http://coffeerings.posterous.com/php-simplexml-and-cdata
{
  public function addCData($cdata_text)
  {
    $node= dom_import_simplexml($this); 
    $no = $node->ownerDocument; 
    $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text)); 
  } 
}
```

and instead of

```
$values->addChild('marque', '<![CDATA['.$product['manufacturer_name'].']]>');
```

use :

```
$values->addChild('marque')->addCData($product['manufacturer_name']);
```

Output is now `<![CDATA[Cyril & Nathalie Daniel]]>`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to remember that **SimpleXMLElement** is doing a double-decode -- instead of mapping `&` to `&amp;` (single-decode), it seems to work to just map `&` to `&amp;amp;` to start with. Your child ends up with `&amp;` in the XML like it should.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to encode your manufacturer name with htmlentities by the looks of it. This should be ok within the CDATA tags I'd have thought though.

Try this:

```
$values->addChild('marque', '<![CDATA['.htmlentities($product['manufacturer_name']).']]>');
```