# adding to child XML cdata

Tags: php, html, xml

I wonder how can i add cdata in xml child? i got this code:

```
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['newtopic'])){
    $topicname = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_POST['topicname']);
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $startedby = $_POST['startedby'];
    $tn = $_POST['topicname'];

    if($topicname == ''){
        $errors[] = 'You`re topic title is missing!';
    }
    if($topicname == ''){
    $errors[] = 'You`re textarea is missing!';
}


    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<topic></topic>');
        $xml->addChild('textarea', $textarea);
        $xml->addChild('desc', $desc);
        $xml->addChild('startedby', $startedby);
        $xml->addChild('date', $date);
        $xml->addChild('topicname', $tn);
        $xml->asXML('topics/sitenews/' . $topicname . '.xml');
        header('Location: sitenews.php');
        die;
    }
}
```

i wanna add the cdata to $textarea part only, i tried already use `'<![CDATA['. $textarea .']]>'` but its not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good news is: You do not need to add CDATA, you can add just text as well. SimpleXML will encode it for you properly. Otherwise, see the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

See here
[How to write CDATA using SimpleXmlElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260224/how-to-write-cdata-using-simplexmlelement)

Copied from the linked example:

```
class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement{ 
  public function addCData($cdata_text){ 
   $node= dom_import_simplexml($this); 
   $no = $node->ownerDocument; 
   $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text)); 
  } 
} 

$doc = new SimpleXMLExtended($xml); 
$element = $doc->addChild('response'); 
$node_note = $element->addChild('note'); 
$node_note->addCData('my cdata guff'); 
var_dump($doc->asXML());
```

Comment: Can you please connect it to my code? i already seen this page.. i using new child not new simple xml element

Comment: i've tried this $cdata = $xml->addChild('textarea', $textarea);
        $cdata->addCData($textarea);

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers like this. If an answer already exists, point it out in the comments or provide it as a dupe once you have reached 3k reputation