# How do I add a link into an xml tag using php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file that I can pull using php and display the results. I need to pick up one of the xml tags and add a link inside it so I can parse the value in the tag as a php variable.
e.g.

```
<name>Llandaff</name>
<firmid>70330</firmid>
<branchid>2</branchid>
```

I want to add a link so the new xml file would be:

```
<name>Llandaff</name>
<firmid><a href="index.php?firmID=70330"></a></firmid>
<branchid>2</branchid>
```

Comment: that's not the problem I'm having, I need to add that into the xml document somehow

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into `<![CDATA[]]>`:

```
<firmid><![CDATA[<a href="index.php?firmID=70330"></a>]]></firmid>
```

To do this with `simplexml`, see accepted answer in this post: [How to write CDATA using SimpleXmlElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260224/how-to-write-cdata-using-simplexmlelement)