# PHP sort and update nodes

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I've been battling with this all day :(

Although I found answers for similar questions they don't update an existing XML, they create a new XML.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is the XML I'm loading and trying to sort just the images->image nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stuff>
    <other_nodes>
    </other_nodes>
    <images>
        <image><sorted_number><![CDATA[1]]></sorted_number></image>
        <image><sorted_number><![CDATA[3]]></sorted_number></image>
        <image><sorted_number><![CDATA[2]]></sorted_number></image>
    </images>
</stuff>

//load the xml into a var
$theXML = //load the xml from the database

$imageNode = $theXML->images;

//sort the images into sorted order
$d = $imageNode;

// turn into array
$e = array();
foreach ($d->image as $image) {
        $e[] = $image;
}
// sort the array
usort($e, function($a, $b) {
        return $a->sorted_number - $b->sorted_number;
});



//now update the xml in the correct order

foreach ($e as $node) { 

//???unsure how to update the images node in my XML

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SimpleXML* is too **simple** for your task. There is no easy way to reorder nodes. Basically, after your sorting routine, you have to reconstruct `<image>` nodes, but you have `CDATA` inside, and *SimpleXML* can't directly add `CDATA` value.

If you want try by this way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260295/3294262) you can find a cool *SimpleXML* class extension that add `CDATA` property, but also this solution use *DOMDocument*.

Basically, IMHO, since every solution require *DOM*, the best way is to use directly *DOMDocument* and — eventually — (re)load XML with *SimpleXML* after transformation:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$dom->formatOutput = True;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'image' );

/* This is the same as your array conversion: */
$sorted = iterator_to_array( $images );

/* This is your sorting routine adapted to DOMDocument: */
usort( $sorted, function( $a, $b )
{
    return
    $a->getElementsByTagName('sorted_number')->item(0)->nodeValue
    -
    $b->getElementsByTagName('sorted_number')->item(0)->nodeValue;
});

/* This is the core loop to “replace” old nodes: */
foreach( $sorted as $node ) $images->item(0)->parentNode->appendChild( $node );

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

<kbd>**[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/8VGvCZ)**</kbd>

The main routine add sorted nodes as child to existing `<images>` node. Please note that there is no need to pre-remove old childs: since we refer to same object, by appending a node in fact we remove it from its previous position.

If you want obtain a *SimpleXML* object, at the end of above code you can append this line:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $dom->saveXML() );
```

Comment: nice one, I wasn't aware that appending = removing!

Comment: @michi me too. I discover it working on this answer. Note that appending = moving (If you append a new child or a child from different node existing children remain untouched)

Answer (score 1):

Consider an XSLT solution using its `<xsl:sort>`. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (whose script is a well-formed XML file) is a declarative, special-purpose programming language (same type as SQL), used specifically to manipulate XML documents and sorting is one type of manipulation. Often used as a stylesheet to render XML content into HTML, XSLT is actually a language.

Most general-purpose languages including PHP (*xsl extension*), Python (*lxml module*), Java (*javax.xml*), Perl (*libxml*), C# (*System.Xml*), and VB (*MSXML*) maintain XSLT 1.0 processors. And various external executable processors like [Xalan and Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (the latter of which can run XSLT 2.0 and recently 3.0) are also available -which of course PHP can call with `exec()`. Below embeds XSLT as a string variable but can very easily be loaded from an external .xsl or .xslt file.

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;    
$xslstr = '<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
           <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
                cdata-section-elements="sorted_number" />
           <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

           <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM (COPIES ALL CONTENT AS IS) -->
           <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
             <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:copy>
           </xsl:template>  

           <!-- SORT IMAGE CHILDREN IN EACH IMAGES NODE -->
           <xsl:template match="images">
             <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="image">
                    <xsl:sort select="sorted_number" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
             </xsl:copy>
           </xsl:template>               
           </xsl:transform>';
$xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// Configure the processor
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);    
echo $newXml;
```

Result *(notice `<![CData[]]>` being preserved)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stuff>
  <other_nodes/>
  <images>
    <image>
      <sorted_number><![CDATA[1]]></sorted_number>
    </image>
    <image>
      <sorted_number><![CDATA[2]]></sorted_number>
    </image>
    <image>
      <sorted_number><![CDATA[3]]></sorted_number>
    </image>
  </images>
</stuff>
```

Comment: No problem. Sorry for the verbosity in info but for future readers I want to encourage XSLT as the other responders went with the usual looping route. Literally minutes after this, I answered a similar [Python question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977447/python-elementtree-xml-modifying-elements-with-multiple-values/35978049), my continued SO campaign to raise awareness of XSLT, an often forgotten lost art.

Comment: Saxon is now available in PHP directly (Saxon/C). There no need to use exec. See the project page: http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the note @ond1. XSLT 2.0 can be used now.

Answer (score 0):

Before going deeper, is a save of the sorted state really necessary? Like in a database, you can always sort items when retrieving them, same here with the code you have already written.

That said, "updating" in your case means delete all `<image>` nodes and add them back in order.

**Update**:
*see fusion3k's answer, that it is not necessary to delete nodes, but just append them. I'd suggest to go with his solution.*

You are using `SimpleXml`, which does not provide methods for copying nodes. You will need to re-create every single node, child-node, attribute. 
Your XML looks simple, but I guess it is an example and your real XML is more complex. Then rather use `DOM` and its `importNode()` method, which can copy complex nodes, including all their attributes and children.

On the other hand, `SimpleXml` to me feels much easier, so I combine both:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$images = $xml->xpath("/stuff/images/image");

usort($images, function ($a, $b){
    return strnatcmp($a->sorted_number, $b->sorted_number);
});
```

Comments:

- `xpath()` is a quick way to get all items into an array of `SimpleXml` objects.
- `$images` is sorted now, but we can't delete the original nodes, because `$images` holds references to these nodes.

This is why we need to save `$images` to a new, temporary document.

```
$tmp = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$tmp->loadXML("<images />"); 

// add image to $tmp, then delete it from $xml
foreach($images as $image) { 
    $node = dom_import_simplexml($image); // make DOM from SimpleXml
    $node = $tmp->importNode($node, TRUE); // import and append in $tmp
    $tmp->getElementsByTagName("images")->item(0)->appendChild($node);
    unset($image[0]); // delete image from $xml
}
```

Comments:

- using `DOM` now, because I can copy nodes with `importNode()`
- at this point, `$tmp` has all the `<image>` nodes in the desired order, `$xml` has none.

To copy nodes back from `$tmp` to `$xml`, we need to import `$xml` into `DOM`:

```
$xml = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;

foreach($tmp->getElementsByTagName('image') as $image) {
    $node = $xml->importNode($image, TRUE);
    $xml->getElementsByTagName("images")->item(0)->appendChild($node);
}  

// output...
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/535800