# Decrease XML node values that are over a certain value

Tags: php, xml

I'm wanting to decrease the value of nodes which have a current value over a certain amount but can't seem to do it.

No errors are occurring but the nodes I want to affect aren't being updated.

Would anyone be able to point out what is wrong with the following:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<property>
<edited>true</edited>
<images>
<image>
<is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
<sorted_number><![CDATA[1]]></sorted_number>
</image>

<image>
<is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
<sorted_number><![CDATA[2]]></sorted_number>
</image>

<image>
<is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
<sorted_number><![CDATA[4]]></sorted_number>
</image>

<image>
<is_required><![CDATA[true]]></is_required>
<sorted_number><![CDATA[5]]></sorted_number>
</image>

</images>
</property>';

$sorted_target_number = 3;

foreach($xml->xpath('/property/images/image') as $tempImgNode){         
$s_number = $tempImgNode->sorted_number;
if ($s_number > $sorted_target_number) {
--$s_number;
}       
};
```

So image nodes with sorted_numbers of 4 and 5 would be changed to 3 and 4.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted didn't run for sure. There's no `SimpleXml` object created.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

To do the subtraction, use the *self-reference-technique*:

```
$s_number[0] = $s_number - 1;
```

It allows updates of `SimpleXml` Elements as well as deletions: `unset($node[0])`. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/2016456

see it working: https://eval.in/536643

The operation above doesn't keep the `CDATA` though. If it is required, you need to take care of that with some extra steps, e.g. [How to write CDATA using SimpleXmlElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260224/2016456) or use `DOM`.

Comment: Thank you. That's got me over the hurdle ;)